# Is MaxLocksPerFile exist in windows CE 6.0 registry?

Tags: windows-ce

Some customers facing out of memory issue in Windows Compact CE 6.0 board. In order to resolve the issue, someone online suggested that if we increase MaxLocksPerFile value in the registry, this problem will be resolved.

But when I saw Windows CE .0 registry using a tool called DM.exe -  I could not find MaxLocksPerFile variable. Because the parent directory of this variable does not exist in the registry file.

Can anybody suggest me how to get this variable in the registry file or is there any alternative or any good way to resolve it. It would be nice if anybody suggest how to recreate the out of memory issue using application programming on windows CE 6.0 issue at the development environment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anybody suggest me how to get this variable in the registry file or is there any alternative or any good way to resolve it.

I dont think this registry value is system wide, it exists probably only for some applications. I have found that office is using it, also MS Access. You should provide full description of the suggestion about MaxLocksPerFile  you have been given.

> It would be nice if anybody suggest how to recreate the out of memory issue using application programming on windows CE 6.0 issue at the development environment.

if you have access to source code, and Visual Studio then you execute your application in debug mode and wait for the crash with Out Of Memory error. You can also add logging to monitor memory consumption. It is also good to ask customers when OOM error occurs. Maybe after few hours of using it. Probably you have some memory leak. It is also possible that some other application is using too much memory.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation.